# hyperref, natbib and PDF/A-compliance

Tags: hyperref, pdf-a

My e-Thesis submission is required to be in PDF/A-1b format, and I'm having difficulty producing output that meets this standard using LaTeX.

I have successfully typeset a chapter using `dvips` to produce a PostScript file, which can then be converted to PDF/A using Adobe Distiller (Acrobat Pro v8.1.2), BUT with the following issues:

1. if I use `hyperref` with coloured links, the conversion fails, because the PS file is not PDF/A-compliant (see below)
2. if I turn on `draft` mode in `hyperref`, the resulting PS file *can* be successfully output to PDF/A using Adobe Distiller, but then I get an error, sometimes 2, while typesetting the bibliography (generated with BibTeX and `natbib` using a custom bibliography style)

For 1) I have seen references to this known issue: hyperlinks are not incompatible with PDF/A per se, but `hyperref` does not include all the flags required for PDF/A compliance:
http://tug.org/mailman/htdig/pdftex/2008-January/007522.html
I tried editing `hyperref.sty` as suggested, but this did not seem to work for me (either when typesetting using `pdftex`, or through `dvips`).  Acrobat still complained about missing Print and Annot flags for each link (citation and cross-references).

I can live with 2) for the official version (no links, but at least it will be 'archive-quality').  Nevertheless, the errors are incredibly annoying.  Each bibliographic entry produces this error:

```
    Argument of \hyper@anchorstart has an extra }
```

and sometimes also:

```
    Paragraph ended before \hyper@anchorstart was complete.
```

These errors never happen when typesetting through `pdflatex`, even in draft mode.  I need to produce a PS file for PDF/A-1b conversion, but these errors are a huge pain.

I can't fully disable hyperref, because I use the `\autoref{}` macro a lot, and I would rather not have to replace all those manually.

I also tried using the `pdfx` package (using the `pdflatex` driver), but got some strange errors very early on in the typesetting run:

```
/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pdfx/pdfx.sty:121: Use of \getTZh 
doesn't match its definition.
<inserted text> D:20121114223403-
                                 05'00'
l.121 \expandafter\convertDate\pdfcreationdate
```

I hope there is enough information above for people to suggest alternatives, or ways to fix the errors.  I haven't put together a MWE, but I could probably throw one together if it would help.

Thanks for any help you can offer.

I am using TexLive 2011 on a Mac (OS X 10.6.8), document processing in TeXShop using simpdftex, Version 20070809
or
pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.3-1.40.12

Comment: ``hyperref`` does have a ``pdfa`` option. Did you try that?

Comment: I could find no reference to a `pdfa` option for `hyperref` in the documentation.
I tried it anyway and, while no LaTeX errors were generated, the resulting PS file could not be successfully converted to PDF/A using Acrobat Distiller :(

Should I be using the `pdfa` option with the `pdftex` driver?  My only concern there is that there are other issues with the resulting pdf file that may prevent conversion to PDF/A.

Comment: @JonathanWhiteley The ``pdfa`` option is explained (here)[http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/hyperref/README]. Don't have any further experience, though.

Comment: The `pdfa` option is new to TeX Live 2012 (I was running 2011).
I upgraded to 2012 and ... same thing happened.  :(
Th `pdfa` option is still not mentioned in the 'official' documentation, and the language in the Readme suggests it is still experimental.  Frankly, I would be happy if I could get `draft` mode to work without spitting out errors for every single bibliography item with the `simpdftex` driver :(
I am also using the `memoir` class - does that make a difference?

Comment: Have you tried ``\usepackage[pdfa]{hyperref}`` and made it the last package?

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure if an answer is still of interest. Anyway:

1) I would strongly advise to use the pdfx package:

```
\usepackage[a-1b]{pdfx}
```

2) The error in the pdfx package is caused by the way how the timestamp is put together. Depending on your timezone (e.g. UTC+1, UTC-1, etc) you have a different sign there. This causes the issue.

```
Use of \getTZh doesn't match its definition.
```

You therefore need to put the pdfx.sty in your working directory and need to adjust that specific line accordingly:

```
\def\getTZh +#1#2{\edef\xTZh{#1#2}\getTZm} % change - to + if error occurs (due to timezone)
```

...

```
T\xHour:\xMin:\xSec+\xTZh:\xTZm}} % change - to + if error occurs (due to timezone)
```

Alternatively, you may change the timezone of your system.

3) pdfx automatically loads the hyperref package, too. If you want to have a customized hyperref setup, you can use:

```
\hypersetup{
   unicode,
   colorlinks=true
}
```

In addition to that, you need to provide a color profile and a valid xmp file. Information on this can be found in the pdfx manual. This solution relies on pdftex.

I'm not aware of any solution using dvips.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try using pdflatex instead of latex-dvips-ps2pdf?

I am actually in a similar situation as I'm also writing my thesis, and I found it is simpler to just generate a pdf directly. I understand this might disrupt quite a few packages but I've been through that with 25+ packages in my preamble quite successfully.

I'm using TeXLive 2012.

Comment: I can successfully typeset using either `dvips` or `pdf(la)tex`, however: 
(1) The pdf file resulting from `pdftex` is not PDF/A - compatible (Acrobat Pro will not convert it). 
(2) The PS file resulting from `dvips` output CAN be converted to PDF/A, but only if `hyperref` is in `draft` mode (which produces errors on every single bibliography item).  
I know PDF links _are_ compatible with the PDF/A-1b standard, I just don't know how to get LaTeX to produce them in a way that is compatible. :(