# Make output pdf consistently viewable on other systems

Tags: fonts, formatting, pdf

I frequently have to submit pdf documents to government systems and want to make sure that my fonts and formatting are preserved intact on these government system.  I have no way of knowing what software they use to access my documents. What is the best way to make sure that my fonts and formatting are preserved intact on these various government systems?

I understand that there are pdf files that contain fonts, and pdf files that rely on the fonts that are already installed on the viewer system.

If your pdf does not have embedded fonts, and the pdf is viewed on a system that does not have those fonts included, then the fonts get "substituted" with undesirable results. (please correct me if I am wrong about this)

How does one produce a pdf that is more likely to be consistently viewable using any pdf viewer on any system?  There is a pdf "X" format, and [Jmakepdfx](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/jmakepdfx?lang=en) written by 
Nicola Talbot.

Is that the entire answer, convert files to PDF/X using Jmakepdfx, or is there another way of looking at this issue, both with regard to how the pdf looks onscreen, and how it would look when printed.  Assuming Jmakepdfx is the answer, would it be possible to use Jmakepdfx within the LaTeX/TeX code rather than use it as a standalone shell script?

Also, are there multiple ways of outputting a pdf file, best practices etc., so that is consistently viewable across platforms/systems.

Comment: This question is too broad and not really related to TeX. The (dis-)advantages of the PDF format have been discussed for years, there are many standards. To produce a PDF/X use the pdfx-package.

Comment: @KeksDose I frequently have to submit pdf documents to government systems and want to make sure that my fonts and formatting are preserved intact. Since I produce all of my documents with LaTeX it seems, at least to me, to be a germane LaTeX question.  Thank you for the pdfx-package reference.

Comment: pdflatex in texlive configuration at least will embed fonts by default, you can always check using acrobat or the pdffonts command line utility which fonts are in or not in the pdf.

Comment: This problem is also discussed here: [http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/169813/].